# How to sort values by their value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got a database consisting of two tables, called 'friends' and 'data'.
Here's what they look like:

friends table:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| UUID (varchar) | FRIEND (varchar) |
+-----------------------------------+
|      Alpha     |       Beta       |
+-----------------------------------+
|      Zulu      |       Zara       |
+-----------------------------------+
|      Gamma     |      Alpha       |
+-----------------------------------+
|      Charlie   |      Alpha       |
+-----------------------------------+
```

data table (does not contain all friends, but only the ones who are online on a server):

```
+----------------+
| UUID  | SERVER |
+----------------+
| Alpha |  lobby |
+----------------+
| Gamma |  lobby |
+----------------+
| Charlie| lobby |
+----------------+
```

So, how do I get a ResultSet like this:

```
+----------------+
| FRIEND| SERVER |
+----------------+
| Gamma |  lobby |
+----------------+
| Charlie| lobby |
+----------------+
| Beta  |  (null)|
+----------------+
```

So basically, that are all the friends of "Alpha" combined with the servers the are on. The friends which are on a server should be on the first place. It should be sorted by the servers!

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain the rules for determining the rows in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is getting the friends of `'Alpha'`.  You can do this using `union all`.  The rest is just a `join`:

```
select a.friend, s.server
from ((select friend from friends where uuid = 'Alpha'
      ) union all
      (select uuid from friends where friend = 'Alpha'
      )
     ) a left join
     servers s
     on a.friend = s.uuid
order by (s.uuid is null) desc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this perfectly working answer :)